# Unable to retrieve information from some of the WorkItem Fields in TFS

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, tfs, tfs-workitem

So these days I am trying to work with the TFS API. So far it was good, but all of a sudden.. I want to retrieve specific story's work items and their respective information using a search by ID method to pick the correct story. In order not to miss some important information I am doing `SELECT *` in my queries. I get the story, I get the Tasks.. But there seems to be problem with few of the fields - namely `AreaPath`, `IterationPath` and `Type`. As a primitive check I've written down some Console prints to check what's good and what's not - so if I `uncomment` any of the three previously named on execution this exception is thrown: `A first chance exception of type 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.FieldDefinitionNotExistException' occurred in Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.dll`.

Here is what I am trying to print out:

```
  Console.WriteLine(target.Fields["Title"].Value);
  Console.WriteLine(target.Fields["Description"].Value);                        
  Console.WriteLine(int.Parse(target.Fields["Id"].Value.ToString()));
  Console.WriteLine(target.Fields["AreaPath"].Value); //Problem 1
  Console.WriteLine(target.Fields["IterationPath"].Value); //Problem 2
  Console.WriteLine(int.Parse(target.Fields["AreaId"].Value.ToString()));
  Console.WriteLine(int.Parse(target.Fields["IterationId"].Value.ToString()));
  Console.WriteLine(target.Fields["State"].Value);
  Console.WriteLine(target.Fields["Type"].Value.ToString()); //Problem 3
```

With or without `ToString()` nothing really changes. 
Any suggestions ?

EDIT: They are not null, I've checked while in Debug mode, they all have assigned values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`CoreField`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.workitemtracking.client.corefield.aspx) or builtin getters:

```
    Console.WriteLine(target.Fields[CoreField.Title].Value);
    Console.WriteLine(target.Fields[CoreField.AreaPath].Value);
    Console.WriteLine(target.State);
    Console.WriteLine(target.Type.Name);
```